# 'Kernel panic-not syncing: Attempted to kill init' while installing CentOS 6.9

Tags: boot, usb, installation, centos

I was trying to install CentOS 6.9 [downloaded from official website (LiveDVD)] in a new assembled PC. The PC came with Windows 10 Pro preinstalled. The specifications of the PC are as follows:

- Inter i5 7th Gen Processor
- 4 GB RAM
- Asus H110M-CS Motherboard
- 2 TB HDD

There was no DVD drive, so first I used a portable DVD drive to install CentOS 6.9. When DVD is selected from the boot menu, the installation will start and after some time the following error occurs.
[image]

Since the portable DVD installation was failing I tried to install from a bootable USB. But I got the same error again and again [I successfully installed Ubuntu from the same bootable USB after these failures]. Then also I tried to install CentOS with no luck. I changed the BIOS settings like Legacy USB, Fast Boot, but no success.

Please help me to install CentOS successfully. Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

At last I tried Netinstall method. I followed this link https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/centos-6-netinstall-network-installation/

But the installation is stuck at step 3.17, after clicking write changes to the disk.
[image]

The PC is stuck that both mouse and keyboard is not working. Restarting is the only option left. What to do now? Please help.

---

ERRORS I GOT:

Earlier I got kernel panic (1st attached image) as the only error. But now I am getting some dracut warnings like:

1. no root device "block:/dev/mapper/live-rw" found
2. boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.

Comment: This usually means that Linux can't find the device it booted off of. Pretty lame but it happens with all sorts of distros and verions

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue myself, but still I don't know what was wrong with the installation.

So here is what I did. After trying a lot I decided to delete all the partitions in the hard disk. So I deleted all the partitions and created 2 new ext4 partitions with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS live disk. After it I tried to boot from the live DVD, but it failed like the previous attempts. Then I tried the Netinstall method by booting from USB and this time the installation completed successfully.

Comment: Note: I had to use Rufus to make the USB drive where LiLi, and Etcher had failed.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what’s causing the kernel panic. Could be any number of things. Can you see any errors before that? If it’s in a GUI loader (not sure if CentOS uses Plymouth), you can hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and see some more detail.

I did find [this](https://darktraining.com/2012/01/23/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-vmware-centos-6.2/) which might be relevant:

> In my case, pressing "Esc" during the boot process showed what was
>   really hanging up the system loading. SeLinux was angry and needed to
>   be disabled.
>
> To do this, just boot off the same CD that you used to install the OS,
>   choose Rescue and answer the first few questions normally, then when
>   it drops you into a shell use:
>
> ```
> vi /mnt/sysimage/etc/selinux/config 
> Set Selinux to 0
> ```

Comment: I also checked the link you provided here. But I can't find the Rescue option when I boot from the disk.

Comment: I also checked the link you provided here. But I can't find the Rescue option when I boot from the disk. Earlier I got kernel panic (1st attached image) as the only error. But now I am getting some dracut warnings like (1) no root device "block:/dev/mapper/live-rw" found (2) boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by numerous things. I had this problem when trying to boot a live USB image of PerfSonar "pS-Performance_Toolkit-3.3-LiveUSB-x86_64.iso"

I learned:

1. This version of CentOS cannot boot from a USB3 device. Ensure you have the USB stick plugged in to a USB2 port, even if it is a 3+ device.
2. The LABEL or CDLABEL called out in the boot loader must match the internally recognized volume label. NOTE: THIS MIGHT BE DIFFERENT THAN THE VOLUME LABEL SHOWN IN WINDOWS!

to solve #2 I had to edit all the boot configs: isolinux.cfg, grub.conf, and bootx64.conf

Change the labels to match what the device actually is. If you use pendrivelinux UUI to make the key it ensures the internal device label is "UUI" even though the volume label seen in windows is "pS-Toolkit". Change everything to be "UUI". The label in Windows and the label shown in the boot configs. That way, all the labels are "UUI" and there is no confusion about what device we are trying to boot from.

After I did that it booted from the USB drive very quickly.